# Back and Exit buttons on one page.. Is it user-friendly?

Tags: usability, navigation, buttons, back-button

We have this app page where in a user needs to fill-out multi-page form. They need to be able to go back to the previous step (hence the back button). But at the same time, they can exit the entire multi-page form to go to the main dashboard anytime (hence the exit / close button), in which case, a draft of the form they're filling out would be saved.

However, is this placement user-friendly? Especially that there's another icon beside the 'exit / close' button.

Is there a better way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Without reading what the top right button does (Go back button), I thought that it would t**ake me back to the previous screen, not previous step, but the place where you clicked in order to get in this form**.

I think that the problem with this screen is the placement of the buttons. On the top level, there should be more "**operational**" buttons: Going back to the previous screen, exit the form and settings.

On the second level, it should be the wizard. The misconception might happen because of the form entity. **Some people perceive the form as one entity and some people every step as a different entity.**

My suggestion is to

- Add **Previous + Next** buttons
- Make **steps look clickable** (so that the user can use them for going back) - [When do users understand that a wizard navigation bar is clickable?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/106369/when-do-users-understand-that-a-wizard-navigation-bar-is-clickable)
- **Remove the Go back button**
- **User Test it!** (because there is a chance that people might perceive it differently than I do)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is. The back button and close button are where users expect them to find.

However, I think the close and settings button might be too close to each other. There's a chance users might click the wrong button. You don't want users to accidentally close their form. You can fix this by repositioning the settings button (do you need settings while filling out a form?) or have feedforward for both buttons ('Are you sure you want to close this form' with a 'yes' and 'no' button in a dialog, for example).

Answer (score 1):

The 'Back'-button should be close to the 'Next'-button - and look the same -since they both are navigational. Maybe you could argue that 'Next' is more important, since it will be used the most. A possibility to make 'Next' more important is to set it wider that 'Back'.

As the others pinpoint, the settings-button is to close to the exit-button, especially when you in fact got enough space to place it elsewhere.

You could use the numbers as navigation, but it will not be as specific as 'Next' and 'Back' buttons. If they're not clickable, you should use another color than your buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there are many elements on top side of the screen.

if you use numbers 1-2-3-4 and circles is possible to use them as a buttons

if you use only 4 dots you only show a status of the processes

I agree @NGAFD have a good Point of View