# Back and Close button in the same native page

Tags: buttons, back-button, close

In this period, the current version of Netflix offers the user who has browsed through several films, the possibility of closing the page or going back through the content history.
To do this, Netflix puts the "X" on the right and the "back arrow" on the left.
Is there any UX documentation I can study for this specific use case? 
Thank you so much! 
[image]

Comment: You should start by going through Netflix's Design System Hawkins (https://netflixtechblog.com/hawkins-diving-into-the-reasoning-behind-our-design-system-964a7357547) and see if there's a good reason for this.

Comment: Here - https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/110003/back-and-exit-buttons-on-one-page-is-it-user-friendly

Answer (score 0):

What would you expect to find in the documentation? Sometimes, design decisions are based on common sense and logic. In the case of Netflix, the arrangement of the 'X' and the back arrow has a rather intuitive explanation. If a user has gone through several steps to reach a specific screen, it makes sense to allow them to backtrack in their navigation. For example, this could apply to going back to a filter, a previous search, a specific position in content scrolling, or all of the above. Remember that there's prior user effort involved, and it could be frustrating to lose that progress.

If a user no longer wishes to continue with the current flow, it would be inefficient to force them to go back to the main section using only the back arrow. That's why the 'X' option is included, which should end the current flow and take the user back to the homepage or the section from which they initiated the action.

Sometimes, it's important to recall that design decisions can be based on intuition and logic and may not always require detailed documentation to support them.

Comment: Just wanted to point out the "Sometimes, design decisions are based on common sense and logic". Really wish it was at least "almost always", instead of "sometimes"... :D